# How do I add a close button to a tab of the MahApps TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I was trying to follow this instruction on how to do it, but I'm just starting out with WPF.

How do I do this using a UserControl that i can reuse in different TabControls?
Also which one is the "Header" ContentPresenter in the [TabControl](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TabControl.xaml) Style?

Below is the instruction found at
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/281

> The other way is to modify/create a style - the issue then is hooking
>   it up to an actual 'close' event in a generic fashion.
>
> If you look at the TabControl style, you'll see the "Header"
>   ContentPresenter. If you wrap that in a stackpanel and add a button
>   like so:
>
> ```
> <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
>   <Label x:Name="root" FontSize="26.67">
>       <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
>   </Label>
>   <Button Content="X" />
> </StackPanel>
> ```
>
> You get :
>
> [image]
>
> If you have that in your Window or UserControl (rather than a resource
>   dictionary), you can wire that up so Click can fire and you can then
>   remove the item from the databound collection or directly from the
>   TabControl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `MetroTabItem`. It comes with the property `CloseButtonEnabled` to enable/disable the close button. You can also bind a command to the `CloseTabCommand` and `CloseTabCommandParameter`.

```
<TabControl xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls">
  <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="The Header of the TabItem"
                         CloseButtonEnabled="True"
                         CloseTabCommand="{Binding CloseTabCommand}"
                         CloseTabCommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}">

    <!-- your content of the TabItem -->

  </Controls:MetroTabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Hope this helps.